# DST settings for php(Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone

I am working on a world clock module in php(codeigniter). I need to display times according to timezone which people select in a drop box. I have completed that, but facing a problem with DST(day light saving) settings. How do i get to know weather that particular timezone has DST for it or not. Kindly help me with this point as I am from India and not familiar with day light savings. Infact got to know about day light saving after working on this project. LOL.. Kindly help.

Comment: OHHHH MY GOD I found the answer to this. PHP has a default tag for DST. It took me 3 days to find that. It was a simple answer but i didn look hard enough

Comment: Put it and accept it as a answer... can help someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (capital i) - Whether or not the date is in daylight saving time - 1 if Daylight Saving Time, 0 otherwise.

Comment: Be sure to set the timezone info first, eg, `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');`, otherwise date() defaults to UTC and you'll not get the result you expect.